# Страницы по ширине сдвигаются влево/ вправо

Tags: html, bootstrap

Всем привет,

Посмотрите, пожалуйста на страницах(там логин отображается над вводом логина)
http://ec2-34-212-140-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/admin/cms-item

http://ec2-34-212-140-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/admin/cms-item/edit?id=75&

При тестировании на Chrome на разных экстрамалых(320px) и малых ( 768px ) девайсах 
страницы по ширине сдвигаются влево/ вправо - как будто что-то распирает верстку по ширине.
В инспекторе обьектов не увидел что распирает - вроде ширина не превосходит макс параметров ширины.

Проверил на http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ - вроде по ширине нормально ...

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду распирает верхний контейнер, где написано Login и #Login? И этот контейнер при малых размерах не много заползает под левое меню?

Comment: Это кажется общая проблема для всех страниц. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на моих ссылках выше.
Там была проблема с логином - я пофиксил 
Сейчас Вы можете зайти в систему ?

Comment: На самом деле, я Вас слабо понимаю. Хотелось бы видеть скриншот, на котором бы Вы показали свою проблему. И если в общем смотреть на Вашу систему, то там достаточно проблем, связанных с позиционированием элементов. Это случается тогда, когда Вы пытаетесь использовать bootstrap и делать то, что bootstrap'ом не предусмотрено. По этому, повторюсь, прикрепите к вашему вопросу скриншоты и больше подробностей о Вашем коде. И тогда мы сможем решить Вашу проблему.

Comment: Тестируя на Chromium 
я настроил на несколько девайсов и тестируя для айпадов(ширина 768 px)
http://imgur.com/a/L7VGi
кликнув мышой и потянув влево/вправо я вижу что страница елозит влево/вправо примерно пикселей на 30
Эта разница видна на принтскринах
http://imgur.com/a/PmWDG

Обычно такре происходит если что-то распирает верстку по ширине
Я этого не вижу

2) Буду благодарен за обозначение проблем и способов их решения в том числе и с позиционированием элементов
Страницы что я делаю требуют бОльшего что я нахожу в примерах...